# How much money would be ideal for 3.5 months in SE Asia?

Tags: budget, thailand, southeast-asia

I will be spending roughly 3.5 months (January to April) in Thailand, Laos and Vietnam. Given the price of food and accommodation in those countries, and transport between countries, how much money should I bring to safely survive for my time there (based on just THOSE 3 factors)? The cheapest means of everything

Comment: In your earlier post you mentioned being there before.  You should know how much you spent per day last time for food and accommodation (prices are similar in all countries you mentioned).  Multiply that by the number of days and add in a few hundred more for bus fares around the area. Otherwise it is just guessing on our part.  I can tell you a bag of steamed rice is 5 baht and a bag of stir fried vegies is 20 baht in a Thai fresh market, but how many bags per meal is enough to keep you running?

Comment: No need to be obnoxious.  If you don't like the answers ignore them, don't be an @$$ yourself. Take some time to research, there are numerous threads on TripAdvisor and ThornTree where backpackers have discussed their spending while in those countries, read, take some notes, do the math.  To expect someone here to map it out for you is just being lazy.

Answer (score 1):

This is Indonesian's standard, which I think is quite similar to those 3 countries. For (decent) foods and drinks, I would say 5€/day. Beer costs around 1€. Accomodation starts from 5€/day, but for tourists from Europe/America, it is advisable to take a more expensive room which may cost around 10-15€. As to transportation between countries, I cannot tell as it depends from what kind of transportation and what your start and destination points are. You can start making your itineraries and come back with a more detailed question.
My advise is to bring your bank card with you. I personally would not bring a lot of cash in my wallet during traveling.

Comment: I'm not bringing "cash in my wallet". I need to know how much to save... If I need to take a second job in the few months now, before this trip.

Comment: Well, you can do the math based on my answer. Add to that, the transportation cost, which depends on your trip plan.